# Is there a way to not show .pyc (Python bytecode) files under Nautilus?

Tags: python, 14.10, python-2.7

Is there a way to disable them under directory structures in Nautilus? My Django-project is getting quite confusing with them.

Comment: Hide them where? Command line or Nautilus, or what?

Comment: @Oli: In Nautilus.

Comment: You may want to look into telling the compiler to put byte code files into a different directory and the interpreter to look for them there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Django, the quickest way might be to stop [generating them in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154443/how-to-avoid-pyc-files).

Now, that might sound like a *terrible* idea... Bytecode precompilation is what makes Python as fast as it is so it's definitely something you want in production, but we can disable bytecode generation just for things run through `manage.py`.

Open it up and add a `sys.dont_write_bytecode = True` line. It should look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

sys.dont_write_bytecode = True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ap.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

<sup>**Warning:** `ap.settings` is specific to *my* project, not yours, and the layout of the file may be different in your version of Django... Be careful if you copy the whole thing!</sup>

Production uses (like through a wsgi server) should skip over `manage.py` and still generate the bytecode files, but in development —where you're more likely to use `./manage.py runserver`— should stay clean.

This *will* slow things down a little though.

---

Oh and to clean up:

```
# Python 2
find /path/to/project -name '*.pyc' -type f -delete

# Python 3
find /path/to/project -name '__pycache__' -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Be aware that **both these statements delete files**, so you might want to check them (remove the `-delete` or `-exec ...` statements) before running this hot. They'll just show you what files match.